# Is postback works only in pageload?

Tags: asp.net, autopostback

May be this question seems illogical but i want to explore it.
I have if statement and i want to postback page within that statement but not in page load.
my code is

```
if (Request.QueryString["HotelID"] != null)
            {
                //here i want to set autopostback true
            }
```

so my page post back when it have query string.

Comment: please explain more . . .

Comment: i have tab container and tab panels in tab container and now i want to post back my page to call initialize culture,
may be this question helps you to understand what i am looking for.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515939/auto-post-back-property-not-working-with-tab-container/15540226?noredirect=1#15540226

Comment: May be you are looking for Response.Redirect()