# Postback page on query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, autopostback

this question is duplicated of [Is postback works only in pageload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540048/is-postback-works-only-in-pageload?noredirect=1#comment22017961_15540048)
I want to post back page when i have value in my query string.
see code

```
if (Request.QueryString["HotelID"] != null)
// here i want to post back 
{
```

how i can post back page ?

Comment: `postback` or `redirect`?

Comment: i want  to postback page not redirect

Comment: why do you want to postback on this condition? I don't think it is possible. There may be other way. you should explain what do you want after postback.

Comment: @Shekhar i want to post back my page to call initialize culture..see this question for what i actually want...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515939/auto-post-back-property-not-working-with-tab-container

Comment: @Shekhar i just want to do that when i click on edit button which is on another page then my first page on which query string value comes from edit button postback the page to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if (Request.QueryString["HotelID"] != null)
{
    Page_Load(sender, e);
}
```

Or this:

```
if (Request.QueryString["HotelID"] != null)
{
    Response.Redirect(Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath.ToString());
}
```

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["HotelID"]))
{
     Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
    or
     Response.Redirect("yourpagewithpath.aspx");
}
```